# ActiveMQ / PHP Stomp use TextMessage instead of BytesMessage

Tags: php, activemq-classic, stomp

when I send a message to ActiveMQ using [PHP-Stomp](https://pecl.php.net/package/stomp) the message is sent as BytesMessage. However I would like to send an TextMessage.

According to the [STOMP documentation](http://activemq.apache.org/stomp.html) this can be achieved by not sending an content-length header:

> ... The protocol does however support a content-length
>   header. To provide more robust interaction between Stomp and JMS
>   clients, ActiveMQ keys off of the inclusion of this header to
>   determine what message type to create when sending from Stomp to JMS.
>   The logic is simple:
>
> Inclusion of content-length header => Resulting Message
>
> yes => BytesMessage
>
> no => TextMessage
>
> This same logic can be followed when going from JMS to Stomp, as well.
>   A Stomp client could be written to key off of the inclusion of the
>   content-length header to determine what type of message structure to
>   provide to the user.

In my test PHP script I have not defined the content-length header and it seems to be automaticly added.
I also tried passing content-length as 0, false or null. In all of these cases it produces a BytesMessage.

So my question is, **how do I produce a Textmessage instead of BytesMessage**.

My code looks like the following:

```
<?php

$stomp = new Stomp('tcp://localhost:61613');
$stomp->send('/topic/test.central_message_topic', 'testmessage', [
    "persistent" => "true",
]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer.

**TL;DR: It is not possible.**

With the PECL-Stomp it is not possible to not send the content-length header, since it is automaticly created when the request is sent. If you pass the reuqest will contain two content-length headers.

For reference [the sourcecode](http://git.php.net/?p=pecl/tools/stomp.git;a=blob;f=stomp.c;h=a1462433b347b63af1d3645a3daaf55489646f58;hb=HEAD#l342).

Answer (score 5):

it's been a long time but this worked for me :

```
try {  
$stomp->send("your_queue", "your_message", array("amq-msg-type" => "text"));
} catch (StompException $e) {  
die('send failed: ' . $e->getMessage());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add transformation header, using this with activemq:

```
$stomp->send('/queue/pizzamonsters', json_encode($frame), [
    'transformation' => 'TEXT'
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$stomp = new Stomp('tcp://localhost:61613');
$stomp->send('/topic/test.central_message_topic', 'testmessage', ["content-type" =>"text/plain"]);
```